# Error after install mocha in meteor

Tags: meteor, package, mocha.js

I want to make some test to my software, so I follow some tutorial on the internet and find out the package practicalmeteor:mocha. But after install the package and open the local(without writing any test). I receive the error yelling:

```
socket-stream-client.js:100 Uncaught TypeError: _this._launchConnection is not a function
    at new ClientStream (socket-stream-client.js:100)
    at new Connection (ddp-client.js:435)
    at Object.DDP.connect (ddp-client.js:2340)
    at client_convenience.js (ddp-client.js:125)
    at fileEvaluate (modules-runtime.js:353)
    at require (modules-runtime.js:248)
    at client.js (ddp-client.js:54)
    at fileEvaluate (modules-runtime.js:353)
    at require (modules-runtime.js:248)
    at ddp-client.js:2381
ddp.js:14 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'DDP' of undefined
    at ddp.js:14
    at ddp.js:23
allow-deny.js:22 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'DDP' of undefined
    at allow-deny.js:22
    at allow-deny.js:566
mongo.js:17 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'AllowDeny' of undefined
    at mongo.js:17
    at mongo.js:871
accounts-base.js:23 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'DDP' of undefined
    at accounts-base.js:23
    at accounts-base.js:1462
service-configuration.js:17 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Accounts' of undefined
    at service-configuration.js:17
    at service-configuration.js:73
accounts-password.js:17 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Accounts' of undefined
    at accounts-password.js:17
    at accounts-password.js:329
accounts-ui-unstyled.js:19 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ServiceConfiguration' of undefined
    at accounts-ui-unstyled.js:19
    at accounts-ui-unstyled.js:2113
meteortoys_toykit.js:26 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Mongo' of undefined
    at meteortoys_toykit.js:26
    at meteortoys_toykit.js:410
msavin_mongol.js:20 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Mongo' of undefined
    at msavin_mongol.js:20
    at msavin_mongol.js:1058
autoupdate.js:20 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'DDP' of undefined
    at autoupdate.js:20
    at autoupdate.js:231
practicalmeteor_mocha.js:18 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'DDP' of undefined
    at practicalmeteor_mocha.js:18
    at practicalmeteor_mocha.js:13186
livedata.js:14 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'DDP' of undefined
    at livedata.js:14
    at livedata.js:27
global-imports.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Mongo' of undefined
    at global-imports.js:3
meteor.js:1081 Uncaught Error: Can't find test driver package: practicalmeteor:mocha
    at meteor.js:1081
    at maybeReady (meteor.js:871)
    at HTMLDocument.loadingCompleted (meteor.js:883)
```

I am using meteor 1.6.1.1

Comment: Which driver package for mocha do you use?

Comment: I use the latest version of practicalmeteor:mocha!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will put this as an answer because it may still be relevant so new users that came to the  same point.

`practialmeteor:mocha` is a recommended package but not compatible anymore with Meteor >=1.6.1 and the chance is very high that it is not maintained anymore (as you can see on their open gh issues).

Alternative packages include

- `cultofcoders:mocha`
- `meteortesting:mocha`

Answer (score 0):

I've also met such thing so that it really took me some time to figure out.

According to the **Meteor** *Todo App with Angular* tutorial, `practicalmeteor:mocha` package is recommended. And what an interesting thing is that `meteortesting:mocha` is used in a typical *scaffold* project.

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "meteor run",
    "test": "meteor test --once --driver-package meteortesting:mocha",
    "test-app": "TEST_WATCH=1 meteor test --full-app --driver-package meteortesting:mocha",
    "visualize": "meteor --production --extra-packages bundle-visualizer"
  },
```

However, only using [cultofcoders:mocha](https://github.com/cult-of-coders/meteor-mocha/) which is forked from `practicalmeteor:mocha` did work.

```
meteor remove practicalmeteor:mocha
meteor add cultofcoders:mocha
meteor test --driver-package cultofcoders:mocha
```

Enjoy coding!